# How to convert PlanarConfiguration to separate

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, jai

I convert my .tifs from uncompressed to PackBits compression... However I need to also change the PlanarConfiguration from Chunky to Separate, I do not know how to do this. It's not looking like there's anything on the web about it doing it in Java either. Only people saying to set PlanarConfiguration = 2; Here's my code for the .tif conversion so far...

```
public boolean packBitsConversionMove(File currentDirectory, File currentFile) throws IOException{

try{
        InputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(currentFile));
        PNGImageReaderSpi spi = new PNGImageReaderSpi();
        ImageReader reader = spi.createReaderInstance();

        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fis);
        reader.setInput(iis, true);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(currentFile);

        TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
        ImageWriter writer = tiffspi.createWriterInstance();

        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

        param.setCompressionType("PackBits");

        File fOutputFile = new File(currentDirectory.getPath()  + "\\" + currentFile.getName());
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fOutputFile);
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bi, null, null), param);

    } catch (IOException e){
        return false;
    }   
return true;
}
```

My param variable doesn't have any setPlanarCompression function but I do not know a work around. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hmmm.. According to [JAI TIFF writing **Metadata Issues**](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/package-summary.html#MetadataIssuesWrite), the images are always written with PlanarConfiguartion 1 ("Chunky"): *"PlanarConfiguration if this field is present with value Planar is is reset to Chunky."*

Comment: Ah that's what I was worried about. Any ideas on how to get the LibTiff to use in my java program?

Comment: Comments are for clarification on the current question. :-) I believe that is a completely different question, so you should ask.